# assign list items which are attributes in a viewmodel to table attributes in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller, viewmodel, ienumerable

I am using Asp.net mvc3
In my viewmodel I have taken an IEnumerable attributelike:

```
public IEnumerable<EmployeeDetailsViewModel> EmployeeList{get;set;}
```

In my controller this EmployeeList is having a list of 2*2 matrix. i.e. I have passed an array to this list.
My array name is :`employee`

```
attributes:
First Name
Last Name
Task
```

after result it is displaying employee list in EmployeeList like EmployeeList[0]: values of First Name, Last Name,Task
now I want to store the list values in table in database.

My table also contains similar fields like my array attributes

I am using sql Server 2008 as backend

I want to do this in my controller.
how can I do this?
do I need to use foreach loop to assign list values to attributes of table or need to do something else?
please suggest me something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself resolved the problem:
can use foreach loop here like:

```
 foreach (ModelName item in viewModel.EmployeeList)
                    {
                        TableName a = new TableName();

                        a.Project1up = item.FirstName;
                        a.Employee1up = item.LastName;
                        a.Allocation = item.Task;
                    }
```

Comment: and in the loop itself we can store value one by one in table